# Which URL is better for SEO?

Tags: seo, url

I have 2 main categories:

1. Software
2. Hardware

Each of these categories has 10 subcategories for example hardware: `cpu/graphic/hard disk` and...

Which URL is better for SEO?

1. `www.example.com/hardware/this-is-content.html` or
2. `www.example.com/cpu/this-is-content.html`

Comment: As a side note, if you can build this without the `.html` on the end that would be great, i.e. `www.example.com/hardware/this-is-content`

Comment: The question you should be asking is 'which URL is better for my customers'.

Comment: @John Conde NO! it's not dublicate!...you do nit read question well...

Comment: Reading...how about spelling? ;-) It's a duplicate of the previous question you asked, also marked duplicate (please don't re-ask the same question twice). Also, both are a matter of opinion, and opinion-based questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a third option: `example.com/hardware/cpu/device-name.html`. This way, it's obvious that cpu is a subcategory and hardware is a top category. There are more keywords in the URL this way too. And as a visitor, I really love it if `example.com/hardware/cpu/` and `example.com/hardware/` still work.

Comment: But the seo workers do not suggest it

Comment: https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1630/How+Do+I+Optimize+My+Store+For+SEO%3F#urlstructure is an interesting read. It's a page specifically on how to optimize your store for SEO.